# How to implement error states using Yii Foundation extension FounActiveForm

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I'm using [Yii extension for Foundation 2](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/foundation/) for my Yii project. Installation and using basic UI features is a breeze. However, when I try to implement the FounActiveForm widget, I cannot figure out how to implement the error states. This is the partial explanation from the extension documentation [website](http://foundation.oakwebdev.com/index.php?r=site/forms):

**Error states in Yii Foundation use the wrapper method, you don't have to do anything to get the styles, the extension takes care of it for you.**

What is the wrapper method? How do I implement it in the default yii login page?
This is the code that I'm using:

```
<div class="form">
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('foundation.widgets.FounActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'form',
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
    ),
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($model,'username'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($model,'password'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->checkBoxRow($model,'rememberMe'); ?>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Login',array('class'=>'blue nice button')); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div><!-- form -->
```

With this code, the form errors works fine except that the error class is not present:

[image: sample login page]

This is how it supposed to show the error (example taken from yii foundation website):

[image: sample error state]

Answer (score 0):

It's old tread, but if you still not found answer...

- Download Foundation 3 package from:
  http://foundation.zurb.com/download.php.
- Extract file foundation.css
  (/foundation/stylesheets/foundation.css).
- Replace file in your app extensions directory
  (/protected/extensions/foundation/lib/foundation3/stylesheets/foundation.css)
  with extracted one.